# Facebook login issue in Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, facebook-login, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have integrated facebook login in my app. And it is working fine in Android OS Oreo, Marshmallow, Lollipop and kitkat. But when I test it in 4.2.2 Jelly Bean version, it is like stuck in loading screen. It keeps loading for a very long time.

The Device I am using is
Device Name : Panasonic P31
Android OS : 4.2.2 Jelly Bean

I am sharing the screenshot below.

[image]

Some times **I do get facebook login dialog** telling to **enter email and password**. And if enter the credentials and login, next the **Confirm login** dialog is coming but nothing to interact with, it is blank! Like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also occurred in facebook-android-sdk v4.25.0.
Probably you can fix it by adding the following settings.
It seems to be necessary to handle Facebook Scheme.

/app/res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb{your-facebook-app-id}</string>
```

/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2